# Error using UpdateCursor to copy a GlobalID field

Tags: arcpy, editing, cursor

I am trying to use an Update Cursor to copy a GlobalID field into a string field.  However, I keep getting an error saying "Objects in this class cannot be updated outside an edit session [Medians]".

Aren't I initiating as edit session by using arcpy.da?

The error occurs on the fourth line.

```
workspace = "x/y/z"
edit=arcpy.da.Editor(workspace)
cursor = arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(medians, ("GlobalID", "GlobalID2",))
for row in cursor:
    globalID = row[0]
    globalID = globalID[1:-1]
    row[1]=globalID
    cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Comment: What is your workspace and what is the feature class you are trying to edit? Is it the complete code you run? Does your feature class participate in any kind of geodatabase behaviour (geometric network, topology, network dataset)?

Comment: Hi Alex, I appreciate your response.  I've edited my code to a point where it works (see below).  My feature class is in a file gdb on a network drive.  The feature class had an existing relationship class, so maybe that was the issue?  I've seen elsewhere that this error arises from a versioning problem, but I don't know if this is why I got the error, as my feature class is not in an sde.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found a solution.  I'm not sure entirely why, but changing the code as follows gets rid of the problem:

```
import arcpy
import os

medians = "file.gdb/Medians"
workspace = os.path.dirname(medians)

edit = arcpy.da.Editor(workspace)
edit.startEditing(False, True)
edit.startOperation()

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(medians, ("GlobalID", "GlobalID2")) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        globalID = row[0]
        globalID = globalID[1:-1]
        row[1] = globalID
        cursor.updateRow(row)

edit.stopOperation()
edit.stopEditing(True)
```

This is the [thread that I followed](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/103912) to get this code.

Comment: Just creating an `Editor` isn't enough. The `startEditing` method is used to start an edit session and the `startOperation` method is used to start an edit operation. Required steps in the process. Of course, you could use the `Editor` with a `with` statement, then those steps happen auto-magically.

Comment: thanks olivia this worked for me on a similar issue (using updateCursor on SDE fc)